# How do I properly extend @elastic/elasticsearch to sign requests with aws4?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

What I have:

```
import { Client, Connection } from "@elastic/elasticsearch"
import aws4 from "aws4"

const { ES_AWS_ENDPOINT, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY } = process.env

class AWS4Signed extends Connection {
  request(params, callback) {
    const signed = aws4.sign(params, {
      accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    })

    return super.request(signed, callback)
  }
}

export const signedClient = new Client({
  node: ES_AWS_ENDPOINT,
  Connection: AWS4Signed,
})
```

gives me a truncated host name:

```
ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I am writing this for a Lambda (user: anonymous) to access an IP-restricted endpoint.

Refs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/advanced-config.html

https://github.com/mhart/aws4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this package, after it was updated to use @elastic/elasticsearch:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-elasticsearch-connector